# How do I reverse all Strings in my array?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, reverse

How do I reverse my array output? Like `"peter"` to `"retep"` or `"max"` to `"xam"`

I tried to use collections but it's not working

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;

public class sdf {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] my_friend_names = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
            my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + my_friend_names[i]);
        }

        Collections.reverse(input);
        System.out.println("After Reverse order: " +input);
    }

}
```

Comment: To clarify. You want to reverse the order of the items in the array? Or reverse the order of the letters in the items?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). Please read [ask]

Comment: The bottom line is that the source code you've provided doesn't harmonize with question you're asking. I don't think you understand the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print out `input` which is of type Scanner. Try using `StringBuilder`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] my_friend_names = new String[10];

for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
    my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();

    String reversedName =  new StringBuilder(my_friend_names[i]).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("After reverse: " + reversedName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems you create a string array, but than proceed to try reverse the input. 
If you want to use collections you may do something like this:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(my_friend_names);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    System.out.println("After Reverse order: " + list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code does not compile, for example you call Collections.reverse() on your scanner variable.

Things that might help you.

- You've assumed Collections.reverse() will reverse the Strings within the array - it won't, it simply reverses the order of the Strings, e.g.
- Collections.reverse() works on java.util.List not a primitive array, you can use Arrays.toList() if you need it
- StringBuilder provides a handle reverse() method

Example, use StringBuilder.reverse() to update replace each item in the array with a reversed String

```
String[] my_friend_names = { "fred", "alice" };

for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
    my_friend_names[i] = new StringBuilder(my_friend_names[i])
            .reverse().toString();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(my_friend_names));
```

Output

```
[derf, ecila]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the best way to make a `char[]` from the `String`, reverse that `char[]` and convert it back to a `String`.

Something like this should do the job:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] my_friend_names = new String[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
        my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
    }

    input.close();

    for(String name : my_friend_names) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<my_friend_names.length; i++) {
        char[] characters=my_friend_names[i].toCharArray();
        List<char[]> reverse=Arrays.asList(characters);
        Collections.reverse(reverse);
        my_friend_names[i]=new String(characters);
    }

    System.out.println("After Reverse order: ");

    for(String name : my_friend_names) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
```

Let me know whether it works (or not)
Happy coding :) -Charlie